# Verifying Transactions before Finding Nonce

Tags: go-ethereum, nodes, consensus, nonce, proof-of-work

I am trying to learn theoretical fundamentals of Blockchain.
In PoW, the miner who finds the nonce first gets to create next block and all other nodes add that block.
Now, what I don't understand whatif the miner who found nonce actually did not verified any transaction, he just added the in his candidate block and just found nonce, in this way the entire block will be of unverified transactions.

What is the method adopted in PoW to stop miners from doing so?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is no method adopted in PoW to STOP miners from doing so. A miner doesn't have to verify the transactions before adding them to the block, but miners do verify the transactions so the blocks can be accepted by other nodes. It's an incentive. If the block containing unverified transactions were to be added onto the network, it could be detected and rejected by other nodes. If that happens, those miners not only lose the block reward, but also waste the effort expended to find a PoW solution, thus incurring the cost of electricity without compensation.

Comment: So you mean to say that the miner has to verify the transactions as even if he finds the nonce then all the other nodes before accepting his block will actually be checking if all the transactions in his block is verified or not. IS it so ?

Comment: Yes, you are correct.